# What are the purposes of Vishnu's Vyuha avatars?

Tags: vishnu, avatars

The purposes of Shiva's Pancha Bramha Avatars are stated [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16553/who-are-pancha-brahmas-and-why-are-they-called-so). However, what are the purposes of [Vishnu's Vyuha avatars](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/is-there-any-scripture-that-tells-story-about-lord-vishnu-and-mahavishnu/6923#6923)

Comment: So u have two entirely different and unrelated questions under one question..I think its better to ask them separately..

Comment: @Rickros why do say they are unrealated? They both ask abt the function of the avatars of different gods

Comment: Unrelated because one is about Devi and another one about Vishnu..You could have asked 2 questions separately..

Comment: @Rickros oh...k, edited

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vishnu in His **vyūha manifestation which is four-fold (Chatur-vyūha) – Vasudeva (as the creator),Samkarsana  (as the sustainer),Pradyumna (as destroyer - dissolution of the universe) and Aniruddha (as promulgator of spiritual knowledge).** This is the Vaiśnava doctrine of Vyūha or the doctrine of formation. The Chatur-vyūha forms of Vishnu are related to four of the six causes of creation which six are God Himself as the final cause of creation and His five aspects – **Narāyana ('thinking'), Vāsudeva ('feeling'), Samkarśana ('willing'), Pradyumna ('knowing') and Aniruddha ('acting')** successively; each divinity controls its specific creative energy. [**Vyuha**](https://www.revolvy.com/main/index.php?s=Vyuha&item_type=topic)

---

Here is the 
excerpt from [**Shanti Parva ,Mahabharata**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c051.htm)

> I am Brahma, the primeval master of all creatures, have started into
>   birth from Him, and thou hast taken thy birth from me. From me have
>   flowed the universe with all its mobile and immobile creatures, and
>   all the Vedas, O son, with their mysteries. Divided into four portions
>   (viz., **Aniruddha, Pradyumna, Sankarshana, and Vasudeva.**)

I am giving answer about  ,**Samkarsana**  and  ,**Pradyumna** avataras only  Based on  **Bhagvat Purana.**

> **Pradyumna  avatara** -  Pradyumna was son of Lord Krishna  and Rukmini  Pradyumna was born in Dvaraka. **He was the version of God
>   Kamdev.** In the Treta Yuga, Kamdev was burnt by Shiva when he became
>   a barrier to Shiva's meditation. Shiva blessed Kamdev's distraught
>   wife, Rati and promised her that in his next birth Kamdev will be a
>   part of Krishna and Rati will be the daughter of Bhimkaraya Rukmi and
>   that she will marry him. 
>  कामास्तु वसुदेवांशो दग्ध: प्राग
>   रुद्रमन्युना  देहोपपत्तये भुयस्तमेव प्रत्यप स एव
>  जातो वैदर्भ्यां
>   कृष्णवीर्यसमुद्भव:
>   **प्रद्युम्न** इति विख्याता: सर्वतोsनवम: पितू: ||1 ,2||
>
> kāmas tu vāsudevāṁśo dagdhaḥ prāg rudra-manyunā dehopapattaye bhūyas
>   tam eva pratyapadyata sa eva jāto vaidarbhyāṁ kṛṣṇa-vīrya-samudbhavaḥ
>   **pradyumna** iti vikhyātaḥ sarvato ’navamaḥ pituḥ
>
> Kāmadeva [Cupid], an expansion of Vāsudeva, had previously been burned
>   to ashes by Rudra’s anger. Now, to obtain a new body, he merged back
>   into the body of Lord Vāsudeva. He took birth in the womb of Vaidarbhī
>   from the **seed of Lord Kṛṣṇa and received the name Pradyumna.** In no
>   respect was He inferior to His father.[**SB 10.55.1**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/55/1) and [**SB
>   10.55.2**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/55/2)
>
> ---
>
> Once, Ratidevī approached Pradyumna. **She advised Him to kill
>   Śambara,** and to help Him she instructed Him in the mystic mantras
>   known as Mahā-māyā.
>
> तमिमं जहि दुर्धर्ष दुर्जयं शत्रुमात्मन:
>  मयशतविदं त्वं च
>   मायाभिर्मोहनादिभि: ||14|
>
> tam imaṁ jahi durdharṣaṁ durjayaṁ śatrum ātmanaḥ māyā-śata-vidaṁ taṁ
>   ca māyābhir mohanādibhiḥ
>
> Now kill this dreadful Śambara, Your formidable enemy. Although he
>   knows hundreds of magic spells, You can defeat him with bewildering
>   magic and other techniques. [**SB 10.55.14**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/55/14)
>
> ---
>
> **Sankarshana Avatara -**
>
> तस्य मूल-देशे त्रिंशद्योजनसहस्त्रान्तर आस्ते
>  या वै कला भगवतस्तामसी
>   समाख्याताsन्त इतिsसात्वतिया
>  दृष्टदृश्यो: संड.कर्षम् अहमित्यभिमान
>   यं संड.कर्षम् इति आचक्षते ||1||  
>   tasya mūla-deśe
>   triṁśad-yojana-sahasrāntara āste yā vai kalā bhagavatas tāmasī
>   samākhyātānanta iti sātvatīyā  draṣṭṛ-dṛśyayoḥ **saṅkarṣaṇam** aham
>   ity abhimāna-lakṣaṇaṁ yaṁ saṅkarṣaṇam ity ācakṣate.
>
> Śrī Śukadeva Gosvāmī said to Mahārāja Parīkṣit: My dear King,
>   approximately 240,000 miles beneath the planet Pātāla lives another
>   incarnation of the Supreme Personality of Godhead. **He is the
>   expansion of Lord Viṣṇu known as Lord Ananta or Lord Saṅkarṣaṇa.** He
>   is always in the transcendental position, but because He is worshiped
>   by Lord Śiva, the deity of tamo-guṇa or darkness, He is sometimes
>   called tāmasī. Lord Ananta is the predominating Deity of the material
>   mode of ignorance as well as the false ego of all conditioned souls.
>   When a conditioned living being thinks, “I am the enjoyer, and this
>   world is meant to be enjoyed by me,” this conception of life is
>   dictated to him by Saṅkarṣaṇa. Thus the mundane conditioned soul
>   thinks himself the Supreme Lord.[**SB 5.25.1**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/25/1)
>
> ---
>
> यस्य ह वा इदं कालेनोपसंजिहीर्षतोsमर्ष – विरचितरुचिरभ्रमद्भ्रुवोरन्तरेण
>   
>  साडक.र्षणो नाम रुद्र एकादशव्यूहस्त्र्यक्षस्त्रिशिखं
>   शूलमुत्तम्भ्ययन्नु-दतिषठत् ||3||
>
> yasya ha vā idaṁ kālenopasañjihīrṣato
>   ’marṣa-viracita-rucira-bhramad-bhruvor antareṇa sāṅkarṣaṇo nāma rudra
>   ekādaśa-vyūhas try-akṣas tri-śikhaṁ śūlam uttambhayann udatiṣṭhat.
>
> At the time of devastation, when Lord Anantadeva **desires to destroy
>   the entire creation,** He becomes slightly angry. Then from between
>   His two eyebrows appears three-eyed Rudra, carrying a trident. **This
>   Rudra, who is known as Sāṅkarṣaṇa,** is the embodiment of the eleven
>   Rudras, or incarnations of Lord Śiva. He appears in order to devastate
>   the entire creation.[**SB 5.25.3**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/25/1)

**So from these shlokas we come to know that Sankarshna avatar takes place , when lord wishes to destroy the word ,as Sankarshna Rudra.**

Comment: "Pradyumna (as destroyer - dissolution of the universe) ".I thought u said Sanskarshna was the destroyer???

Comment: "Pradyumna (as destroyer - dissolution of the universe) ".I thought u said Sanskarshna was the destroyer???

Answer (score 3):

Your answers are all given in **Srimad Bhagavatam**.

> **SB 4.24.36:**
>
> My Lord, as the supreme directing Deity known as Aniruddha, You are
>   the master of the senses and the mind. I therefore offer my obeisances
>   unto You again and again. You are known as Ananta as well as
>   **Saṅkarṣaṇa** because of Your ability to destroy the whole creation by
>   the blazing fire from Your mouth.
>
> **SB 3.26.21:**
>
> The three types of egotism (ahankara) are technically known as
>   vaikarika, taijasa and tamasa. The mahat-tattva is situated within the
>   heart, or chitta, and the predominating Deity of the mahat-tattva is
>   Lord **Vasudeva**.
>
> **SB 5.17.16:**
>
> In Ilāvṛta-varṣa, Lord Śiva is always encircled by ten billion
>   maidservants of goddess Durgā, who minister to him. The quadruple
>   expansion of the Supreme Lord is composed of **Vāsudeva**, **Pradyumna**,
>   **Aniruddha** and **Saṅkarṣaṇa**. Saṅkarṣaṇa, the fourth expansion, is
>   certainly transcendental, but because his activities of destruction in
>   the material world are in the mode of ignorance, He is known as
>   tāmasī, the Lord's form in the mode of ignorance. Lord Śiva knows that
>   Saṅkarṣaṇa is the original cause of his own existence, and thus he
>   always meditates upon Him in trance by chanting the following mantra.
>
> **SB 3.26.27-28:**
>
> The mahat-tattva is transformed into three divisions: Vaikarika,
>   egotism in goodness (sattvika-ahankara), from which the eleventh sense
>   organ, the mind, is manifest and whose predominating Deity is
>   **Aniruddha**.
>
> **SB 3.26.29-31:**
>
> Taijasa, or egotism in passion (rajasa-ahankara), from which the
>   senses and intelligence are manifest and whose predominating Deity is
>   Lord **Pradyumna**.
>
> **SB 3.26.32:**
>
> Tamasa, or egotism in ignorance, from which sound vibration
>   (shabda-tanmatra) expands. From the sound vibration, the sky (akasha)
>   is manifest and, the senses, beginning with the ear, are also
>   manifest.

Regarding the 4 weapon combination we have the 24 Vaikuntha planets in the spiritual sky, wherein each one of them reside as Lords. The 24 forms are all tattvas with a name, which are deified and worshipped in the form of Shaligrama. Each Shaligrama has a particular deity and a method of worship.

Its mentioned in the **Garuda Purana**.

> ***Chapter XLV - Characteristic marks of Shalagrama Stones (Shaligram)***
>
> Hari said:— As a side issue of this discourse I shall, describe the
>   characteristic marks of Shalagrama (Shaligram), by touching which
>   stone, one has the sins, accumulated in a koti of births, dissipated.
>
> The holder of conch-shell, discus, club and lotus, known as Keshava,
>   is [also called] Gadadhara [the holder of mace]. The Lord Narayana is
>   also the holder of lotus, the bow Kaumodaki, discus and conch-shell.
>   He is the holder of discus, conch-shell, lotus and club and is also
>   named Madhava and Shri Gadadhara. Govinda, Gadadhara, the holder of
>   club, lotus, conch-shell and discus is adorable.
>
> Salutation unto thee of the form of Vishnu, the holder of lotus and
>   the conch-shell, unto thee of the form of Madhusudana, the holder of
>   conch-shell, lotus, club and discus. Salutation unto that form of
>   thine which holds the club, conch-shell and lotus, unto that form,
>   which is of three foot steps, unto that form which holds the bow
>   Kaumodaki, lotus and conch-shell and unto thy dwarfish form Vamana.
>   Salutation unto thee the holder of conch-shell, lotus, discus and
>   club. Salutation unto that form which bears the mystic mark of
>   Srivatsa, unto Hrishikesha, and the wielder of lotus, club,
>   conch-shell and discus. Salutation unto the holder of lotus, discus,
>   club, conch-shell, unto Padmanabha (lotus-navelled), unto Damodara,
>   unto the wielder of conch-shell, discus, club and lotus. Salutation
>   unto Vasudeva, unto the holder of conch-shell, club and lotus.
>   Salutation unto Sankarshana. Salutation unto the form of Pradyumna,
>   the holder of a beautiful conch-shell, a beautiful club and a
>   beautiful lotus. Salutation unto Aniruddha and the wielder of club,
>   conch-shell and lotus. Salutation unto the Purusottama form with
>   lotus, conch-shell, club and discus. Salutation unto the form of
>   Adhokshaja, the holder of club, conch-shell, and lotus. Salutation
>   unto Man-lion form, the holder of lotus, club and conch-shell.
>   Salutation unto the form, Achyuta, the wielder of lotus, conch-shell
>   and club. I will bring here Janarddana with his conch-shell, discus,
>   lotus and club and Upendra with his wheel, club, lotus and conch-shell
>   Salutation.
>
> Salutation unto this form of Hari, holding a beautiful discus, lotus,
>   dub and conch-shell. Salutation unto the form. Srikrishna weilding
>   club, lotus, wheel and conch-shell.
>
> The Shalagrama stone, known as **Vasudeva**, is of a white colour and
>   possesses two ring-like marks around its mouth. The one, known as
>   **Sankarshana**, is of a red colour, has two ring-like marks around its
>   mouth or lateral aperture and has the mark of a lotus on its eastern
>   side. The one, known, as **Pradyumna**, is of a yellow colour, has a small
>   ring-like mark, is of an elongated shape and bears on its surface a
>   large number of impressions like pin-holes. The one, known as
>   **Aniruddha**, is of a circular shape and blue colour and is marked with
>   three lines around its mouth. The one known as **Narayana** is of a black
>   colour, contains the mark of a club-like line in its cavity and has
>   the circular mark at the navel or a little raised up. The **Narasimha**
>   alone is elevated on the breast, is of a tawny colour, and is dotted
>   with fine spots; while a **Varaha** resembles a Sakti in shape and has two
>   rugged and uneven circular marks. A **Sthula** stone is of blue colour,
>   has three lines, is of the form of a tortoise and is dotted with
>   marks. The stone, known as Krishna, is round and depressed at the
>   back. **Sridhara** has the marks of five lines, that of a garland of
>   forest flowers and that of a club. The **Vamana** stone is of a round and
>   puny size and **Sureshvara** has a circular mark on its left side. The
>   one, known as **Anantaka**, has various forms and bears an impression like
>   the hood of a serpent. The **Damodara** stone is thick, of blue colour,
>   and contains a circular mark of blue colour in the central part of the
>   cavity. **Brahma** stone has a small mouth and is of thick blue colour.
>   **Sushira** stone has marks of long lines, while **Amvuja** stone has the  > mark
>   of one circular figure and is thick. A **Sthulachakra** stone has deep
>   holes and is dotted with dark marks. A **Hayagriva** stone is of the shape
>   of a goad; while a **Kaustava** stone possesses marks of five lines. A
>   **Vaikuntha** stone is of the hue of a gem on the hood of a serpent, of
>   dark colour and bears one circular mark. A **Matsya** stone is of the
>   shape of a long lotus and has marks of lines at the mouth. A
>   **Trivikrama** stone bears the mark of a circle on the left side, that of
>   a line on the right side and is of a dark-blue colour.
>
> Salutation unto the holder of club who is situate in Shalagrama
>   (Shaligram) as well as in Dvaraka.
>
> A **Lakshmi Narayana** stone is of the shape of a Kadamva flower, bears
>   marks of four circles at one mouth, is adorned with the figure of a
>   garland of forest flowers, is marked with golden lines and cow’s
>   hoofs.
>
> The **Sudarshana** class has got only a single circular mark, while the
>   existence of two characteristics the class Lakshmi Narayana. The
>   Trivikrama class has got three circular marks, the Chaturvyuha class
>   has got four, the Vasudeva class has got five, the Pradyumna class has
>   got six, the Sankarshana class has got seven, the Purusottama class
>   has got eight, the Navavyuha class has got nine, the Dashavatara
>   class has got ten, the Aniruddha class eleven, and the Dvadashatma
>   class has twelve circular marks. The Ananta class bears more marks
>   than twelve. He, who reads this poem, describing the forms of Vishnu,
>   repairs to the celestial region.