# Which scriptures gives details about the Ashta-Lakshmi?

Tags: scripture, worship, lakshmi

There are said to be eight forms of *Devi Lakshmi*, called as [*Ashta Lakshmi* ( अष्ट - लक्ष्मी )](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashta_Lakshmi) .

Which all scriptures give details about them?

I'd like to further know, if they are to be considered as a parallel to the [*Vyūha* manifestations of Lord *Vishnu*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16818/what-are-the-purposes-of-vishnus-vyuha-avatars?r=SearchResults) or just normal incarnation manifestations like the *Nava-Durgas* or the *Dasha-Avataras* ?

How does, and which scriptures define their origin, significance and mode of worship?

---

Please try to include (if possible), all the scriptures which might give details about the *Ashta-Lakshmi* concept.