# What Mantra should be chanted while wearing Five-faced Rudraksha?

Tags: scripture, shiva, shiva-purana, rudraksha

I wear a Rudraksha with 5 faces / Panchamukhi.

I read somewhere that there are certain mantras to be chanted while wearing it.

can anyone tell how can I know which one is associated with the Rudraksha I wear.

thanks.

Comment: You wear the kalagni rudraksha on ur own? I also wear one but only after someone prescribed..

Comment: Yes i wore by my own

Comment: That is why u don't know the rules. Ideally u should wear only under someone's guidance.

Comment: okay. thank you. Will read the purana as per the comments below. As I am  more inclined to Lord Shiva, he happens to be my kul-devta.

Comment: Okay...........

Answer (score 5):

Shiva Purana Vidyesvara Samhita Chapter 25 describes about the greatness of Rudraksha.

For the five-faced Rudraksha (Pancha Mukhi Rudraksha) Shiva Purana states:

> पञ्चवक्त्र स्वयं रुद्र कालाग्निर्नामत प्रभुः ।
>   सर्वमुक्तिप्रदश्चैव सर्वकामफलप्रद ।।
>  
>   **Rudraksha having five faces represents Rudra himself and is known by the name Kãlagni. It fulfills all the desires, bestows salvation to the devotees.**

Regarding the mantra to chant while wearing five faced Rudraksha it states:

> ॐ ह्रिं नमः 
>   Om Hrim Namaha

As a sidenote Mantras are not supposed to be chanted and applied just because you see it here or in other places. One should have authority to chant mantra. So, I suggest you at least you read that chapter from *Vidyesvara Samhita (Chapter 25)*, so that you can have authority from Shiva Purana itself to chant it while wearing.

There are also seperate mantras which are to be chanted while wearing Mãlã of Rudraksha or while wearing it in specific places. Like the use of [PanchaBrahman Mantras.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16553/who-are-pancha-brahmas-and-why-are-they-called-so/16557#16557) That chapter of Shiva Purana (Vidyesvara Samhita Chapter 25) makes it clear regarding recitation of other mantras.

Comment: you mean to say by reading the chapter, one gets authorized to chant the mantra. otherwise he is not ? 

is it the chapter or the whole purana, as i am planning to read the whole purana.

Comment: @Vishwas Goswami Yes, reading the whole Purana is the best idea... I told that chapter because I mentioned 'at least'.

Comment: okay thank you. can you tell me if there are any rules/restrictions for reading the purana as well. 

and which author or version has the best description. Preferred English/Hindi/Gujarati.

Comment: @Vishwas Goswami Well, if you are doing special Puja like Shiva Purana Parayanam or something like that than there are rules regarding reading/ listening of the Shiva Purana (Vidyesvara Samhita chapter 6)... If you want to read it for your knowledge (out of devotion towards Shiva) you can download it from Google drive upload link of Shiva Purana here...https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9078/complete-english-translations-of-puranas It is nice and it gives English translations just after Sanskrit verses...

Comment: @Vishwas Goswami Regarding the other rules also there are so many rules that it is not possible to follow them all in present context... so the best thing is to Surrender on Shiva and chant his names and meditate on him.. you can chant Eight names (Bhava, Rudra, Sarva, Ishana...)... also one doesn't need to get afraid of rules while you are fixing your mind in Shiva... because Shiva is Brahman... and sins can't touch the person who is fixing his mind in Brahman (Maitryanai Aranyaka)... so if you have devotion you don't need to get afraid of rules.. Shiva will take care of them all...