# Are there examples of deities sitting on another deity, except a female deity sitting on her spouse?

Tags: gods

Lakshmi is seated on Vishnu's chest and is called विष्णुवक्षस्स्थलस्थिता (Residing in Vishnu’s Chest)

The supreme Goddess is seated on Sadasiva per this post;

[Who are Pancha brahmas' Lalita Devi sits on and Why are they called so?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16553/who-are-pancha-brahmas-lalita-devi-sits-on-and-why-are-they-called-so)

Are these the only examples in scripture?

Answer (score 0):

**Sri Kālika Upa-Purana Chapter 58.:**

> विष्णुब्रह्माशिवैरदेवै ध्रियते सा जगन्मयी।
>
> **सितप्रेतो महादेवो ब्रह्मा लोहित पङ्कजं।।** 65
>
> This Jaganmayi Devi Shivā is always borne by Vishnu, Brahma and Shiva; **for Mahadeva is the preta and Brahma is pink lotus.**
>
> **हरिर्हरिस्तु विज्ञेयो वाहनानि मनोजसः।**
>
> स्वमूर्त्या वाहनत्वन्तु तेषषा यस्मान्न युज्यते ।। 66
>
> **Hari is lion, and these Tridevas serve as Vahanas of the illustrious Devi.** However, the three of them cannot attain Devi's Vahanatva in their individual forms.

I hope this helps.